# Fast screen space gradient effect

Tags: css, performance, css-gradients

I want to create an effect, where an element on a scrollable page has a gradient background that changes with its scroll position, so the gradient always stays the same and the child elements are kind of like a "window" to said gradient.

I have successfully created such an effect (see JSFiddle below) by using a SVG image with a gradient fill as a `background-image` and `background-attachment: fixed`, but the resulting scrolling performance is pretty terrible, especially in Chromium browsers. Looking at the performance profiler in DevTools reveals the `Paint` segment of each frame takes more than four times longer to complete compared to when the effect is disabled.

Now my question: Is there any way to achieve the same result while being a lot less resource-intensive?

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 648px;
}
.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto max-content;
  grid-template-columns: auto max-content max-content;
  grid-template-areas: 'a a a' 'b c d';
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMnB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMycHgiPjxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyI+LmF7b3BhY2l0eTowLjA1fS5ie2ZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzAwMDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6ODtzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcDpzcXVhcmU7c3Ryb2tlLW1pdGVybGltaXQ6MTB9PC9zdHlsZT48ZyBjbGFzcz0iYSI+PGxpbmUgY2xhc3M9ImIiIHgxPSIzMiIgeTE9IjAiIHgyPSIwIiB5Mj0iMzIiLz48bGluZSBjbGFzcz0iYiIgeDE9IjMyIiB5MT0iMzIiIHgyPSIwIiB5Mj0iNjQiLz48bGluZSBjbGFzcz0iYiIgeDE9IjMyIiB5MT0iLTMyIiB4Mj0iMCIgeTI9IjAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+"),  url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDBweCI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJhIiBncmFkaWVudFRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDkwKSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjODBjMGZmIiAvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmYzA4MCIgLz48L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PjwvZGVmcz48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNhKSIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
  background-size: 32px, 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
}
.sub-child-1,
.sub-child-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: #0c0;
}

.child>span { grid-area: a; }

.sub-child-1 { grid-area: c; }
.sub-child-2 { grid-area: d; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a `position:fixed` element instead

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 648px;
}
.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto max-content;
  grid-template-columns: auto max-content max-content;
  grid-template-areas: 'a a a' 'b c d';
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  clip-path:inset(0); /* clip the pseudo element to only its parent */
}
.child::before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMnB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMycHgiPjxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyI+LmF7b3BhY2l0eTowLjA1fS5ie2ZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzAwMDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6ODtzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcDpzcXVhcmU7c3Ryb2tlLW1pdGVybGltaXQ6MTB9PC9zdHlsZT48ZyBjbGFzcz0iYSI+PGxpbmUgY2xhc3M9ImIiIHgxPSIzMiIgeTE9IjAiIHgyPSIwIiB5Mj0iMzIiLz48bGluZSBjbGFzcz0iYiIgeDE9IjMyIiB5MT0iMzIiIHgyPSIwIiB5Mj0iNjQiLz48bGluZSBjbGFzcz0iYiIgeDE9IjMyIiB5MT0iLTMyIiB4Mj0iMCIgeTI9IjAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+"),  url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDBweCI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJhIiBncmFkaWVudFRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDkwKSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjODBjMGZmIiAvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmYzA4MCIgLz48L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PjwvZGVmcz48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNhKSIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
  background-size: 32px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat, repeat-x;
}
.sub-child-1,
.sub-child-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: #0c0;
}

.child>span { grid-area: a; }

.sub-child-1 { grid-area: c; }
.sub-child-2 { grid-area: d; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```